# Can't install sampledata with Magento 2.1.3

Tags: magento2

I'm just installed Magento with the following archive :
Magento-CE-2_1_3_sample_data_tar_bz2-2016-12-13-09-29-31.tar.bz2

At the end of the install, I got this message :
[image]

Details from the logs :

```
/var/www/html/magento2$ cat var/log/system.log
[2017-01-05 08:17:20] main.ERROR: Sample Data error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`, `sku`, `has_options`, `required_options`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [] []
[2017-01-05 08:22:48] main.ERROR: Sample Data error: No such entity with cartId = 1 [] []
```

How should I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have used none empty database for Magento 2.1.3 installation.

Create an empty database and then try to install.